# CreateProcess procedure not working

Tags: delphi, winapi

The following piece of code doesn't make an application to run. Can some one please point out what could be the problem?

```
procedure TTestForm1.DR_DBA_StartAppButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  StartInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcInfo: TProcessInformation;
  filename : String;
  sa : TSecurityAttributes;
  sd : TSecurityDescriptor;

begin

  InitializeSecurityDescriptor( @sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION );
  SetSecurityDescriptorDacl( @sd, true, nil, false);

  sa.nLength := sizeof( sa );
  sa.lpSecurityDescriptor := @sd;
  sa.bInheritHandle := true;

  // start app process
  ZeroMemory(@StartInfo, SizeOf(TStartupInfo));
  StartInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);

  if not
    CreateProcess (nil, PChar(SF_AppPathBox.Text), @sa, @sa, False,
    PROCESS_VM_WRITE or PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, nil, nil, StartInfo, ProcInfo) then
  begin

    showmessage ('Cannot Start App');
    exit;

  end;

end;
```

This code ran perfectly well for an older alpha build with different UI but now after the implementation of a new UI design, it doesn't.

The GetLastError function returns an error code of 2, the system cannot find the file specified.

The path defined is correct as it is extracted from the installdir registry entry made by the application. I have also tried manually including it but to no avail.

`'X:\App\PB 0.93\PB.exe'`

I am using DxScene v4.42 for UI design and the path is extracted from TVxTextBox. Putting in constant path works but not from the text box although both are system strings. I have compared both strings with each other through CompareStr which resulted in a complete match.

I am working on Windows 7 64/32bit and Windows XP SP2/3 32bit.

## Findings

DxScene components inherently use unicode strings which are incompatible with createprocess procedure.

So I stored the required path strings first in normal strings and then passed them as parameter to create process which worked.

Comment: probably you can tells us at least error codes, numeric and textual, and whic line exactlye they start to happen.

See MSDN GetLastError, SysInternals Process Monitor

http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What does "doesn't allow" mean? Error codes or messages? What does "somehow it doesn't" mean? We have no way to see your screen or read your thoughts from here, so it's necessary for you to provide those details to us. Please edit your question to add more specific details, so we can help you solve your problem. :-)

Comment: @Ken White: Helpful comment to a new poster.

Comment: @David Hefferman: "Call GetLastError when the API call fails." That would have been a good comment. The other three sentences were unhelpful.

Comment: @max Maybe I should have said nothing. But if a dev doesn't know how to call GetLastError then there's not much any of us can do to help.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to all this application programming and am more of a microcontroller/FPGA programmer. I'll try GetLastError then.

Comment: Not related with your problem but your dwCreationFlags are not correct, in effect you're calling the function with `NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS` (= $00000020 = PROCESS_VM_WRITE) + `DETACHED_PROCESS` (= $00000008 = PROCESS_VM_OPERATION)

Comment: @Ken White: I am flabbergasted at your response to my comment. I didn't say you were impolite! I complimented your comment. I thought it was good and said so. However, I promise, I will never again respond to one of your comments (or if you prefer to have me removed from posting questions or comments, there must be some way for you to do that).

Comment: @David Hefferman: Sorry you took offense at my response to your comment. I still think when you pointed to GetLastError, it was a good comment. Everything else was a putdown and absolutely unnecessary. Like Ken, you seem to be sensitive to responses to your comments, but happy to put down the rest of us dummies who lack your experience. I will refrain from commenting on your posts in the future. (Or you can have me banned, if you prefer.)

Comment: @MaxWilliams, I apologize. I misunderstood what you intended - I thought you were criticizing both my comment and David's, and couldn't understand what I had said wrong. :-( My apologies to you. Of course I don't want you removed here - we try and welcome everyone. Feel free to comment on anything I say - I will try to read more carefully in the future. :-) I've removed my comment so as not to be misleading to others.

Comment: @Max Actually I was agreeing with you.

Comment: Is it possible that SF_AppPathBox.Text is an AnsiString and you are using a Unicode Delphi? Or vice versa. You could copy SF_AppPathBox.Text into a local variable of type string before calling CreateProcess. You should also call UniqueString on that local variable since CreateProcess may modify it. As is clearly stated in the documentation.

Comment: @David Kinda. I have found a workaround, please see my edited post.

Comment: There you go. That's the vice versa in my comment. You can pass Unicode strings to CreateProcess, but you'd need to use CreateProcessW. And make sure you used a writeable buffer as per docs. Clearly you are on an Ansi Delphi. You could simply pass PChar(string(SF_AppPathBox.Text)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you have a mismatch between Unicode and Ansi text. You are using UI controls that use Unicode, but are compiling in an Ansi Delphi. So you are passing an array of 16 bit characters to a function that expects 8 bit encoded text. Which explains the error code that is reported.

It's possible that the code worked for the original developers because they used a modern Unicode Delphi. If that is the case then your best course of action is to compile the code with the version of Delphi in which it was originally compiled.

If you must use an Ansi Delphi then you can fix your code by passing

```
PChar(string(SF_AppPathBox.Text))
```

to CreateProcess. That will have the effect of converting from Unicode to Ansi.

You could alternatively call the Unicode version of CreateProcess like this:

```
CreateProcessW(..., PWideChar(WideString(SF_AppPathBox.Text)), ...)
```

Comment: Well they used the same environment I am using, Delphi 2007. Though now, I am thinking of migrating to firemonkey due to its similarity to DxScene and as D2007 is very very buggy.

Comment: XE2 is much better than 2007. But remember that FMX is bug city at the moment. My advice would be to wait for XE3 and hope that has a less buggy FMX.